# URL pattern is not working to invoke controller

Tags: html, thymeleaf

My application login layer is implemented using Spring security.
But "Forgot Password" is not working since this link is on login page only and session will start only if user would be logged in to application. So please suggest me a way to invoke my controller by clicking on "Forgot Password" link on login page (withoud login to application or without start of session).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add itrercept rule for this link, like

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/forgot-password/**" filters="none" />
```

Comment: <sec:intercept-url pattern="/forgot-password/**" filters="none" /> this worked. Thanks a lot @iMysak

Comment: @PushpendraVerma : Kindly mark the reply as answer if you feel this answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an href that points to the ForgotPasswordController.
Keep a requestMapping that is authenticated anonymously. You would not need a session to pass your data there.